# Strong exception guarantee for std::unique_ptr<T>::reset

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a function `reset`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void reset(unique_ptr<T>& p, Args&&... args)
{
    // implementation (1)
    p.reset(new T(forward<Args>(args)...));

    // implementation (2)
    p = make_unique<T>(forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Am I correct that:

1. For implementation (1), if an exception is thrown during the destruction of the original pointee of `p`, the `new`-ed memory will be leaked;
2. For implementation (2), nothing can ever be leaked;
3. And so we should prefer (2) to (1).

Comment: Note that in general, if your system has destructors that can throw exceptions, it's essentially impossible to be exception-safe, since the stack-unwinding logic will call destructors, and C++ doesn't support multiple simultaneously active exceptions. See *Effective C++*, 3rd edition (though it's probably in earlier editions as well), Item 8: "Prevent exceptions from leaving destructors."

Comment: The example that's supposed to motivate "prefer `make_unique` to `new` " is, `f(new A(), new B())` vs `f( make_unique<A>(), make_unique<B>())`. In this case order of evaluation is unspecified and if either `A` or `B` ctor throws the other can be leaked. `make_unique` prevents those leaks. When there's only a single pointer being `new`'ed, you probably don't strictly need `make_unique` but its generally a good idea to avoid explicit `new` of heap objects and use idioms that get things inside an RAII object as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 4):

As Jonathan Wakely [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447426/strong-exception-guarantee-for-stdunique-ptrtreset/38447460#comment64300470_38447460), the point is moot, because behaviour of `unique_ptr::reset` is undefined if the destructor throws anyway.

Both versions have UB if the destructor throws, so this is not a reason to prefer one over the other.

[[unique.ptr.single.modifiers]](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#single.modifiers-4) (standard draft)

> 3 Requires: The expression `get_deleter()(get())` shall be well formed, shall have well-defined behavior, and **shall not throw exceptions**.

---

Even if the behaviour was well defined...

(1) Would not leak. `unique_ptr` takes ownership of the parameter before destructing the old one.

> 4 Effects: Assigns `p` to the stored pointer, and then if the old value of the stored pointer, `old_p`, was not equal to `nullptr`, calls `get_deleter()(old_p)`. [ Note: The order of these operations is significant because the call to `get_deleter()` may destroy `*this`.  — end note ]

---

Reasons to prefer one over the other

- (1) requires only C++11, (2) requires C++14 or your own boilerplate for `make_unique`.
- (2) doesn't have explicit call to `new`, so it is easier to reason about memory tidyness using the old rule of thumb: "one delete for each new".

Comment: +1, _but_ it's a precondition of `unique_ptr` taking ownership of a pointer that invoking the deleter (which is `std::default_delete` by default) will not throw an exception. That means it's undefined behaviour if (1) _or_ (2) throws an exception, so neither option has to be exception-safe, they could both call `std::terminate()` (or do something worse like corrupt the heap).

Comment: @JonathanWakely good point, that makes the point of the question moot.

Comment: Also, [res.on.functions]/2 bans throwing destructors across the board.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void reset(unique_ptr<T>& p, Args&&... args)
{
  auto tmp = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  std::swap( tmp, p );
}
```

As noted by the other answer, `reset` demands the destructor does not throw.

The above, however, makes no such demands.  `swap` should never throw.  If the ctor in `make_unique` throws, obvious things happen.  The ctor of `tmp` does not throw.

If the dtor of `tmp` throws, it already contains what `p` contained, and `p` already contains the new data.  So things are in a predictable state.

This is not the strong exception guarantee, because if a throw occurs (during destruction of what was in `p`) things are not rolled back to the original state.  I can think of no logical way to provide that guarantee: maybe if `clone` of `T` is nothrow?  But even then if `p` throws, so would any temporary object, so things aren't really practical.

Answer (score 3):

All of `~unique_ptr`, `unique_ptr::operator=` and `unique_ptr::reset` are `noexcept`. So, throwing exception from destructor of an object, owned by `unique_ptr`, will always result in `std::terminate`. Which makes memory leaks irrelevant in both cases.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) it is explained why `make_shared`/`make_unique` are preferable to `unique_ptr(new ...)`/`shared_ptr(new ...)`. This is why we should prefer (2) to (1)

Don't forget: you cannot specify custom deleters with `make_shared`/`make_unique`.